# From which URL does "sudo apt-get source" fetch the source tarball?

Tags: apt, package-management

How to tap into the exact url from where the source tarballs for ubuntu packages are downloaded, when we execute the below command?

```
sudo apt-get source {package-name}
```

I know that the url is derived from the below line in sources.list, but what would be the exact url for a package?

```
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tarballs are stored in the repositories’ “pool”; in your case, [the Ubuntu pool](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/). In there you’ll see directories for each suite (“main”, “restricted”, “universe”, “multiverse” in your `deb-src` line). Inside those, you’ll find alphabetical directories, containing one directory per *source* package (the `Source:` entry in `apt show`’s output), and the tarballs are in there — for example, [the `glibc` pool](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/).

The source indexes are stored in the “dists” section; in your case, start from [Xenial’s “dists”](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/), find the relevant directory for the suite you’re interested in, and look in the “source” directory there.

You can ask `apt-get` to show you the relevant URLs, without downloading anything:

```
apt-get source --print-uris glibc
```

This works with both binary and source packages.